# Pkzip - CRC-32 in Central directory file header

Tags: zip, docx, crc32

i am searching the internet to find what Fields are calculating by crc-32 of the Central directory file header as mentiond here
[wiki-zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format))

[image]

as you can see there are some calculation but i don't know what fields are entered to this calculation, the main reason i want to do this is because i want to enter some data to the comment field and still that a docx file(=pkzip) could be open on office 2007+ without the message of corrupted file, i am pretty sure after long research is that it has something to do with the CRC-32 Calculation.

if there are any other ideas i be glad to hear them

## EDIT

i now try to hide more info at the extra feild and get that the file is coruptted althought i added the size to the footer

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply inserting a comment in the central directory, then the problem has nothing to do with the CRC.  You are messing up the size of central directory in the end of central directory field.

Comment: +! for handling the comment! , i now try to hide more info at the extra field but get corrupted any ideas?

Comment: Yes.  My idea is that you read the [PKZIP appnote](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

Comment: That document has everything you need to create and modify zip files, completely describing the format.